# Planetscope images atmospheric correction

Tags: envi, planet, atmospheric-correction, flaash

I have downloaded an image which is level 3B processed (so I already have surface reflectance), but my assignment is to compare the data values of the SR file with my results. 
At first I applied radiometric calibration in the AnalyticMS file and then tried to put the result in FLAASH but it didn't work.
From what I read, I realised that the AnalyticMS is already calibrated but it is not in a BIL/BIP format that FLAASH needs. So do I need to convert this file (.tif) in BIL/BIP format and then apply FLAASH? And if so, how do I do the conversion?

Comment: Joanne, could you please provide a bit more of context? Are you using Envi? Which version? Does FLAASH documentation of your version specify that it can correct Planetscope data? What makes you think that it is only a file type issue?

Comment: Hi Andrea and thank you for your time to comment on this. I am using ENVI v.5.5 and the exact issue is that in the box "sensor type" in FLAASH, the "Planetscope" option is missing, therefore I need to specify some extra information in the Multispectral settings. I get the error message that I need a filter function file. As far as the FLAASH documentation you mention, do you refer to the spectral library files? If so, there is nothing related to Planetscope there. But I thought I could use FLAASH anyway.